# SQL - How do I calculate active subscribers by day

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, window-functions

The SQL below allows me to view active subscriptions on a specified date that I manually enter into @report_date. Instead I want to show a graph of our active subscribers over the past two years, thus i'd like to be able to group by every day in the past 2 years. However, I am unsure how I can make @report_date loop through every day in the past year.

Unfortunately, the logic behind the cancellation table is questionable. Every time a customer reactivates their subscription the cancellation row is updated to set "reactivated" to 1. If a customer cancels a second time a new row in the cancellation table is made with "reactivated" set to the default 0. Thus, to find someone who was cancelled on @report_date, either "reactivated" has to be set to 0 or if they have reactivated, then their reactivated_date must be after @report_date.

```
    set @report_date = '2020-06-11';

    SELECT
        @report_date AS Date,
        COUNT(DISTINCT s.customer_id) AS 'Active Subscribers'
    FROM
        subscriptions AS s
    WHERE
        (authorized = 1 OR authorized = 0)
        AND s.created_date < @report_date
        AND s.customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id
                                  FROM cancellations
                                  WHERE (reactivated = 0 OR reactivated_date > @report_date)
                                     AND cancellation_date < @report_date);
```

Subscriptions Table:

```
customer_id  |  created_date  |  authorized
1               2020-06-06       1
2               2020-06-07       1
3               2020-06-08       -1
4               2020-06-08       1
```

Cancellations Table:

```
customer_id  |  cancellation_date  |  reactivated  |  reactivation_date
1               2020-06-09            1               2020-06-10
2               2020-06-12            0               NULL
4               2020-06-10            1               2020-06-12
```

Current Output:

```
Date        |   Active Subscribers
2020-06-11      1
```

Desired Result:

```
Date        |   Active Subscribers
2020-06-12        2
2020-06-11        1
2020-06-10        1
etc.
```

Comment: This data looks like a real mess.  What happens if a subscriber reactivates more than once?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I completely agree. The database was built by an outsourced agency before I began working here. If a subscriber reactivates a second time, the "reactivated" field in the second cancellation row is set to 1.

Comment: You should provide clearer data to handle these situations.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How do you mean exactly? I've simplified the data as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is consistent, one option uses `union all`, window functions and aggregation:

```
select date, sum(is_active = 1) active_subscribers
from (
    select 
        customer_id, 
        date, 
        sum(sum(active_cnt)) over(partition by customer_id order by date) is_active
    from (
        select customer_id, created_date date, 1 active_cnt from subscriptions where autorized in (0, 1)
        union all
        select customer_id, cancellation_date, -1 from cancellations where reactivated = 1
        union all
        select customer_id, reactivation_date, 1 from cancellations where reactivated = 1
    ) t
    group by customer_id, date
) t
group by date
order by date
```